# How do I run gst-device-monitory-1.0 from Docker

Tags: docker, gstreamer

I have been looking for this for some time now but I can't get `gst-device-monitor-1.0` to work from a Docker container.

`$ gst-device-monitor-1.0` finds a bunch of devices and prints to stdout.
`$ docker run --rm -it --privileged ggoussard/gstreamer gst-device-monitor-1.0` just prints

```
Probing devices...

No devices found!
```

I have tried with `--dev=/dev/snd` but that does not help.

What do I need to pass to my docker command to have gstreamer find my devices on host?

Comment: A major design goal of Docker is to hide the host's hardware devices from containers.  This process needs to be run on the host directly.

Comment: I may be wrong but I thought the design goal was to hide it per default but still let you access hardware from the host like `docker run --device=/dev/i2c-0 <image>`. Why is gst-device-monitor different? What access does it need that docker prohibits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this!

I used

```
> strace gst-device-monitor-1.0 Video/Source 2>&1 | grep ^access
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/run/udev/control", F_OK)       = 0
access("/sys/subsystem", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.3/5-2.3:1.0/video4linux/video1/uevent", F_OK) = 0
access("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.3/5-2.3:1.0/video4linux/video0/uevent", F_OK) = 0
access("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.3/5-2.3:1.0/video4linux/video0/uevent", F_OK) = 0
access("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2.3/5-2.3:1.0/video4linux/video1/uevent", F_OK) = 0
```

on my machine to find out what the tool needs access to. Then it was easy: just mounting `/run/udev` from the host by adding `-v /run/udev:/run/udev` to the docker run command did the trick! `gst-device-monitor-1.0` now works inside my docker container as expected.